# Gaussian distributions - a question about convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, normal-distribution, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mu_n$ be Gaussian distributions with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1/n$ and $f$ a function.

It may be true that if $\underset{\mathbb{R}}{\int} f \mu_n dx \rightarrow  \underset{\mathbb{R}}{\int} f \delta_0dx$, then $\mu_n \rightarrow \delta_0$? Why yes or not?  If yes, in what conditions?

$\underset{\mathbb{R}}{\int} f \mu_n dx \rightarrow  \underset{\mathbb{R}}{\int} f \delta_0dx$ $\Leftrightarrow \underset{\mathbb{R}}{\int}f (\mu_n - \delta_0) dx \rightarrow 0 \Leftrightarrow \mu_n \rightarrow \delta_0$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: The question is sort of jumbled. The $\mu_n$ converge to $\delta_0$ as distributions. Start there. Then figure out what the author means by "function".

Comment: What type of convergence are you talking about when you write $\to$?

Comment: pointwise convergence

Comment: "pointwise convergence" No, these are numbers (for the integrals) or measures. Pointwise convergence applies to none of them.

Comment: $\mu_n(x) \rightarrow \delta_0(x)$ a.e $x$?

Comment: What does "$\mu_n$ converge to $\delta_0$ as distributions" mean?

Comment: $\mu_n(x)$ does not exists for $x$ in $\mathbb R$ (and neither does $\delta_0(x)$, actually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu_n$ be the gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1/n$.

Then $\displaystyle\int_\mathbb R f(x) \mu_n(\mathrm dx) \to f(0)$ for every bounded measurable function $f$ continuous at $0$.